# Bootstrap Popover - Images appearing in wrong position until 2nd click

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a number of buttons on my page that when clicked should display content inside a Bootstrap Popover. The content is loaded from my Database and can be either text or an image which can vary in size.I have implemented a solution which is working correctly in IE however in Chrome and Firefox my popover is opening half way down the page when you first click the button. On the second click of the same button the image will then appear in the correct position  with no issue just like in IE.  If the content of the popover is text then it is displayed correct first time in all browsers but the issue appears for images in Chrome and Firefox. I have researched this but I cannot find anything that has helped it to work across all browsers. Any help would be great.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-content="@item.Content">@item.Title</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                html: "true",
                placement: "top",
            });  
    });
```

**CSS**

```
popover{
width:auto!important;
max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I am using Bootstrap v3.3.7

Comment: The issue seems that when inserting the image in the popover the popover animation is blocked thus the image is rendered wrongly. Is it possible to take a look at your function which injects the image? In the meantime try with the delay option for the popover "delay: { "show": 1000, "hide": 1000 }" and see if something changes

Comment: I added the delay to my code but the results are the same, works in IE but chrome and firefox couldnt render it properly until the second upload. The image is add from an Admin area in my site, a user selects a file and then it is saved into the DB. I will add the function to my question.

Comment: I'm sorry but I meant the function when you click the button to display the popover. How do you inject the image inside the popover? I expect you are using the "content" parameter in the popover passing a function right?

Comment: No worries at all. In the HTML button I am adding adding a link to my image at the data-content parameter. For example : data-content="@item.Content". This is point to a link of the image stored in the application.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue (at least this was the case for me) was one of caching.  The button is clicked, the popover loads its content, the `<img />` tag is added to the DOM and begins a fetch, the popover renders, and the fetch completes and is blitted to the screen.

The best solution I've found is to preload/the image.  There are two ways you can do this.  If you know your image url ahead of time, you can add a [preload link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content).  Alternatively, you can place the popover content that includes the image tags in a `<div class="d-none">...</div>` (or `class="hidden"` if you're using bootstrap 3).

```html
<html>
<head>
    <!-- case where image urls are known ahead of time -->
    <link rel="preload" as="image" href="my-image.png" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- 
        case where image urls are NOT known ahead of time
        NOTE: @item.Content should not include <script> tags or the code will be run twice
    -->
    <div class="d-none">
        @item.Content
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="popover"
            data-container="body" data-content="@item.Content">
        @item.Title
    </button>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(() =>
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                html: "true",
                placement: "top",
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is actually a perfect answer to the problem!
As I´m retrieving image link from DB and on the first load the image was not retrieved and thus the calculation done properly, all I needed was to load the image another time but I hid it with display:none. 

This makes sure that image is fetched from DB and stored locally, thus once you want to hover over element that triggers popover, is loaded from cache, boom!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may come across the same issue as this I have the found adding the line - trigger: 'hover', to the script allowed images to be loaded in the correct position on each browser.

Comment: Can you put example how do you fix this issue?

Comment: Hi. In the end up I used a different plugin which I felt was a better solution for the application I was working on.

Comment: please share it